# Executors not completing all the task

Tags: java, runnable, executorservice, executor

Hi I am trying to run below code, and after executor is terminated I am expecting the count of remaining task to be 0, but for some reason it's more then 100 when it satisfy below condition.

```
 while(executor.isTerminated()) {
                System.out.println("Total Task Remaining : " + ExecutorServiceExample.task.size());
                System.out.println("*** Executor Terminated ***");
                break;
            }
```

Code Snippet.

```
package test;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ExecutorServiceExample {

    public static volatile Set<String> task = new HashSet<String>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            String name = "task#" + i;
            task.add(name);
            Runnable runner = new TaskPrint(name);
            executor.execute(runner);
        }

        try {
            executor.shutdown();
            executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (executor.isTerminated()) {
                System.out.println("Total Task Remaining : " + ExecutorServiceExample.task.size());
                System.out.println("*** Executor Terminated ***");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }
}

class TaskPrint implements Runnable {

    private final String name;

    public TaskPrint(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        ExecutorServiceExample.task.remove(name);
    }
}
```

Something strange with the result based on the number of tasks.

Output for 100 tasks.

```
Total Task Remaining : 0
*** Executor Terminated ***
```

Output for 1000 tasks.

```
Total Task Remaining : 0
*** Executor Terminated ***
```

Output for 10000 tasks.

```
Total Task Remaining : -27
*** Executor Terminated ***
```

Output for 100000 tasks.

```
Total Task Remaining : 1205
*** Executor Terminated ***
```

Comment: I don't know, but I know that creating 2 thousands of threads with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2000);` is asking for trouble...

Comment: I'm wondering why this doesn't exit with a ConcurrentModificationException because the HashSet is not synchronized...

Comment: @G.Demecki I changed it to `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);` now the Total task remaining is more then 2000

Comment: `Total Task Remaining : 37`
`[task#1666, task#1668, task#1667, task#1908, task#1913, task#1912, task#1911, task#1910]`
`*** Executor Terminated ***`

Comment: What's the java version? HashSet is not thread-safe, but since 1.7 HashSet size() may not return negative count

Comment: Isn't the executor expected to complete all tasks ?

Comment: @locoyou java version is 1.8

Comment: You may try to run the above code snippet.

Comment: `public static volatile Set<String> task = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());` fixes the problem.

Comment: What's the deal with `while(executor.isTerminated()) {` and `break`? Why would you write that kind of code, especially if you're using an advanced construct like executor?

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman later I came to know how it works, modified in original post. I hope that is how it is suppose to use. Just trying to get my hands on executor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HashSet` is not thread safe. You can create a synchronizedSet with

```
public static volatile Set<String> task = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<String>());
```